# Regarding multiple dispatcher servlet in Spring

Tags: spring

I have two dispatcher servlets in my application. I write database related config (sessionfactory etc.) in separate  xml file. In each dispatcher servlet config file (abc-servlet.xml, xyz-servlet.xml) I import this common database file.
I am wondering will Spring create two instances of sessionFactory or is it shared with both.
Both application are working fine in my dev environment. I am worried about production if this causes any memory related issues.

Comment: "I have two dispatcher servlets in my application".... is there a good reason for this?  It's often not necessary, and usually easier to use just one.

Comment: We Application needs to support 2 different kinds of request. Both  application purpose are quite different and need a different URL for both request.

Comment: Can't you support different request types and urls using a single servlet with multiple @RequestMappings? For example: @RequestMapping(value="url1" RequestMethod.Get), @RequestMapping(value="url2" RequestMethod.POST) What more would you need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From DispatcherServlet [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html):

> A web application can define any number of DispatcherServlets. Each servlet will operate in its own namespace, loading its own application context with mappings, handlers, etc. Only the root application context as loaded by ContextLoaderListener, if any, will be shared.

So, you're sessionFactory will only be shared if it's defined in an app context loaded by the [ContextLoaderListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html), otherwise not.